# Counting the number of customers by values in a second series

Tags: python

I have imported a list of customers into python to run some RFM analysis, this adds a new field to the data for the RFM Class, so now my data looks like this:

```
                                   customer RFMClass
    0  0001914f-4655-4148-a1dc-1f25ca6d1f15      343
    1  0002e50a-5551-4d9a-8734-76307dfe2131      341
    2  00039977-512e-47ad-b929-170f18a1b14a      442
    3  000693ff-2c61-425c-97c1-0286c874dd2f      443
    4  00095dc2-7f37-48b0-894f-910d90cbbee2      142
    5  000b748b-7ea0-48f2-a875-5f6cb95561d9      141
...
```

I'd like to plot a histogram showing the number of customers in each RFM Class, how can I get a count of the number of distinct customers ID's per class?

I tried adding a `1` to every row with `summary['number'] = 1` thinking that it might be easier to count these rather than the customer ID's, as these have already been de-duped in my code, but I can't figure out how to sum these per RFM Class either.

Any thoughts on how I could do this?

Answer (score 0):

I worked this out by using `.groupby` on my RFM class and summing the 'number' I assigned to each row:

```
byhour = df.groupby(['Hour']).agg({'Orders': 'sum'})

print(byhour)
```

This then produces the desired output:

```
      Orders
Hour        
0        902
1        438
2        307
3        162
4        149
5        233
6        721
```